# Pointers, memory allocation: index of rows in Matrix Multiplication (C Programming)

Tags: c

I'm having trouble understanding what an "index of rows of a" in the problem is referring to... can you give me an example of that? Why does

```
sum = sum + a[(row * a_cols) + k] * b[k * b_cols + col]?
```

Thank you!

```
double dotProduct(double a[], const unsigned a_rows, const unsigned a_cols,
                  /* a is a matrix with a_rows rows and a_cols columns */
                  double b[], const unsigned b_cols,
                  /* b is also a matrix.  It has a_cols rows and b_cols columns */
                  unsigned row, // an **index of a row of a**
                  unsigned col) // an index of a column of b
{
    int k; // loop variable

    double sum = 0.0; // the result of the dot product is stored here
    k = 0;
    while (k < a_cols) { // recall: a_cols == b_rows
            /* we need to multiply a[row, k] and b[k, col] and add that to sum */
            sum = sum + a[(row * a_cols) + k] * b[k * b_cols + col];
            /* recall a[i,j] is stored at a[(i * a_cols) + j]
                  and b[i,j] is stored at b[(i * b_cols) + j] */
            k += 1;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: A 'for' loop would be cleaner than the 'while' loop in this context; also use 'k++' (or '++k') in preference to 'k += 1'.  And this illustrates when the comments are so profuse that they start to get in the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** my bad, forget my first answer, I misunderstood the question...

Answer:
The 5th argument to the dotProduct() method, named *row* is given as ***an index of rows of a***.
This means that **it is a 0 to (a__rows -1) value to be used to designate one particular row of the "matrix" a**.  (Effectively it could be a 1 to a__rows value instead. This is merely a matter of convention; math folks tends to like the "1-based" indexes, programmers prefer the 0-Based values. See Adam Liss' funny comment on this topic in remarks)
Since the matrix a is implemented in a one dimensional array, you need to use simple arithmetic to address the all the cells of a that are on the row indexed by *row*.

The "formula" is to visit all these cells in order is

```
for (int c = 0; c < a_cols; c++)
{
    A_Cell_Value = a[row * a_cols + c];
}
```

A similar formula is to be applied to scan the cells of a given *column* of b.  however in that case, *col*, the index, will be used as an offset and b_cols as a factor. Specifically,

```
// not an error this is a_cols which also corresponds to the number of rows of
// matrix b, so that these matrices would be compatible for multiplication    
for (int r = 0; r < a_cols; r++) 
{
     B_Cell_Value = b[(r * b_cols) + col];
}
```

I think the above provides you the necessary understanding to iterate trough the cells of a row or a column.  I let you put this all together in your application.

**A few hints**: 
  - do some **parameter value checking**.  This will avoid getting out of bound errors on these matrices.
  - a good way to **introduce abstraction** in your program would be to introduce a function which returns the value of a single cell of a matrix, from the matrix dimension and two row and column index.  For example:

```
// returns the matrix's cell value at RowIdx and colIdx
double GetCell(double matrix[], int nbOfRow, int nbOfColumns,
               int rowIdx, int colIdx)
{
   if (rowIdx < 0 || rowIdx >= nbOfRows ||
       colIdx <0 || colIdx >= nbOfColumns
      )
   {
      printf("bad arguments in GetCell()\n");
      return 0;   // print
    }
    return matrix[rowIdx * nbOfColumns + colIdx];
}
```

In this fashion you would abstract (=hide the details about) these ugly matrices stored linearly, and be able to address them in terms of row and column index at the level of the dot product formula. 
In other words, the GetCell() function worries of finding the right cell, based on its knowledge of the structure of the matrix implementation.  It doesn't have to know what this cell value is going to be used for.  The DotProduct calculation logic worries about which series of cells of A to multiply with which series of cell of B, addressing each of these cells "naturally" in term of their row/column (i/j etc.) "coordonates" and it doesn't need to know how the data is effectively stored in the matrix implementation.

Comment: It clearly isn't: the comment comes after the variable "row".

Comment: @Kinopiko.  Dang you're right! Didn't see that comment. I fixed reply accordingly.

Comment: +1 for sneaking in some sensible programming habits along with a clear and thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it seems that **`a`** and **`b`** are two matrices: **`a`** has dimensions `a_rows` x `a_cols`, and **`b`** has an unspecified number of rows and `b_cols` columns.  (Actually, the missing `b_rows` must equal `a_cols` for the math to work.)  The function is calculating the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the `row`<sup>th</sup> row in **`a`** and the `col`<sup>th</sup> column in **`b`**.  The formula for a dot product (1  <= *`k`* <= `a_cols`):

> ∑ **a**`[row ,`*`k`*`]`**b**`[`*`k`*`, col]`

In English, this means you multiply the numbers in the `row`<sup>th</sup> row in **`a`** with numbers in the `col`<sup>th</sup> column in **`b`**, one pair at a time, and then add the products.

So, to answer the original question: **`row` tells you which row in `a` is involved in the dot product.** The code represents each matrix as a vector (*i.e.* a one-dimensional array), and Kinopiko's answer explains how to find the number at a particular row and column.  (And now you understand why un-commented "clever" programming tricks usually aren't.)

---

Aside:  this may be the last vector-math question I tackle.  The wiki markup is *killing* me!  :-)

Comment: Before someone complains:  In math circles, matrix indices generally start with 1.  In C, array subscripts usually start with 0.  This is why mathematicians and programmers can never agree on which floor to get off the elevator.

Answer (score 1):

One tricky part not so far explained by others is that if you have a vector (linear array) of, say, 24 elements, you can treat it as a two dimensional array - in fact, as a number of different two dimensional arrays.

As a 2 x 12 array:

```
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
```

As a 3 x 8 array:

```
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
```

As a 4 x 6 array:

```
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
```

As a 6 x 4 array:

```
 0,  1,  2,  3,
 4,  5,  6,  7,
 8,  9, 10, 11,
12, 13, 14, 15,
16, 17, 18, 19,
20, 21, 22, 23,
```

As an 8 x 3 array:

```
 0,  1,  2,
 3,  4,  5,
 6,  7,  8,
 9, 10, 11,
12, 13, 14,
15, 16, 17,
18, 19, 20,
21, 22, 23,
```

Or as a 12 x 2 array:

```
 0,  1,
 2,  3,
 4,  5,
 6,  7,
 8,  9,
10, 11,
12, 13,
14, 15,
16, 17,
18, 19,
20, 21,
22, 23,
```

The indexing expression `a[row * a_cols + col]` means you can identify the item in the vector corresponding to the 'row, col' value by multiplying the row number by the number of columns in the matrix (indexing rows from 0), and then adding the column number (also indexed from 0).  Other languages, such as Fortran, index from 1 instead of zero, so you see faintly similar computations using 'row-1, col-1'.

The conditions that the matrix A has `a_cols` columns and `a_rows` rows and matrix B has `a_cols` rows and `b_cols` columns means that you can multiply the matrices A x B, of course.

Comment: Nice example, Jonathan.  I was going to do this, but I could only find 2 configurations for my 29-element vector. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"row" is the row in the matrix a, which is done as a single-index array here. If you think of a as a matrix with `a_cols` columns and `a_rows` rows, then the element of a at row r and column c is `a[r*a_cols+c]`. Here `k` is the column index in matrix `a` and the row index in matrix `b`.

There is a comment right underneath the sum = sum line which explains this already.